# How to script primary key constraints from existing database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a database with 300 tables. I need to clean the tables, so I have written a script which drops all of the constraints, triggers, primary keys, and foreign keys.

I have managed to create scripts using the *generate scripts* feature, but they only include primary keys inside the CREATE statements.

I need to get them as ALTER TABLE statements so that I can drop the keys, clear database, insert new data, and restore all the keys, constraints, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to drop the constraints to clear the tables and insert data?

Comment: As @jle-s comment alludes to - a PK constraint is no obstacle to deletion - so maybe don't drop them in the first case? (Equally, any Unique constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell and SMO are going to be your friends here:

```
$option_drop = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions;
$option_drop.ScriptDrops = $true;

"" > drop_primary_keys.sql
"" > create_primary_keys.sql

$server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server ".";
$db = $server.Databases['AdventureWorks'];
foreach ($table in $db.Tables) {
    foreach ($index in $table.Indexes) {
        if ($index.IndexKeyType -eq "DriPrimaryKey") {
            $index.Script( $option_drop ) >> drop_primary_keys.sql
            $index.Script() >> create_primary_keys.sql
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of notes here:

- Running this script will nuke any existing files of the name "drop_primary_keys.sql" and "create_primary_keys.sql", so proceed with caution
- The script doesn't take into account any foreign keys since you said you already have a way to do that.
- You may have to tweak the ScriptingOptions object to fit your needs.  Specifically, I'm using the defaults on the create, so you may need to create another ScriptingOptions object and set whichever options you think appropriate.

Other than that, good hunting.

Comment: One other thing to consider: if your primary key is also your clustered index, it'll speed things up if you either disable or drop any non-clustered indexes on the table since dropping the clustered index will force a rebuild of all of the non-clustered indexes as will adding a clustered index to a heap.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error though:
Property 'IndexKeyType' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and
 is settable.

Very strange, since the docs for Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index clearly say that there should be such a property

Comment: Oh I see what's wrong... the = should be -eq. Otherwise, the output looks good so far. Will post back when I have time to test it. Thanks Ben

Comment: Ah crap... you're right.  I thought I'd run it from where I copy/pasted it, but apparently not.  Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: It was no hassle. This way I took some time to understand the script instead of just running it:). Everything worked perfectly. Answer accepted.

Out of curiosity, do you know if this API has some way of doing UNIQUE keys? I did those by hand because there was only a handful, but I couldn't find anything in these classes that would let me do it automatically.

Comment: Within the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index class, I see a property called "IsUnique".  Does that do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Msdn has an article about disabling/enabling triggers and foreign keys:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163442.aspx

Comment: This is not at all what I'm looking for. I've already got several ways of disabling triggers and such. none of them work particularly well because you can't truncate even with foreign keys disabled -you have to delete, which takes forever on 300 HUGE tables.

I'm asking how to script all the *PRIMARY* keys as ALTER statements, so that I can add them back after I do what I need to.\

Comment: You just have to modify the above code to use KEY_COLUMN_USAGE and REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS and modify the ALTER statement. The code for the triggers should be valid. You should just generate the ALTER statements to create your keys before you drop them.

Comment: How to generate the primary keys ALTER statements is my question. If I knew how to do that I wouldn't be asking. I already know how to drop constraints and primary keys.